# tcp having trouble connecting c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, image, sockets, tcp

I'm having trouble getting my Sender thread to connect to my Receiver thread. Here's my code below (I'm a novice when it comes to socket programming so if you know a better of sending images over sockets please let me know):

Sender thread:

```
public void SendSS() 
    {            
        try
        {             

            while (!mainFrm.ssStop)
            {
               TcpClient ssTcpClient = new TcpClient();
                ssTcpClient.Connect(mainFrm.contactIP, 1500);                    
                if (ssTcpClient.Connected)
                {
                    Image screenShotBMP = GrabScreen();
                    NetworkStream ns = ssTcpClient.GetStream();
                    memStream = new MemoryStream();

                    screenShotBMP.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);

                    byte[] bytesToSend = memStream.ToArray();                       ;
                    ns.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
                    ns.Flush();

                    screenShotBMP.Dispose();
                    ns.Close();
                    memStream.Close();
                    ssTcpClient.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "frmVoiceChat-SendSS()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Receiver thread:

```
public void ReceiveSS()
    {
        try
        {
            TcpListener ssTcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1500);
            while (!mainFrm.ssStop)
            {
                ssTcpListener.Start();
                TcpClient tcpReceiver = ssTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                //TcpClient tcpReceiver = new TcpClient();
                ssTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                //tcpReceiver.Connect(mainFrm.contactIP, 1500);
                if (tcpReceiver.Connected)
                {
                    labelText("Connected!!!");
                    //NetworkStream receivedNs = tcpReceiver.GetStream();
                    NetworkStream receivedNs = new NetworkStream(tcpReceiver.Client);
                    //ssTcpListener.Server.Receive();
                    //byte[] imageBytes = new byte[tcpReceiver.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    //receivedNs.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                    //MemoryStream receivedMs = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
                    //receivedNs.CopyTo(receivedMs);

                    //Image image = Image.FromStream(receivedNs); // ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid exception here.                        
                    pbScreenShare.Image = new Bitmap(receivedNs);

                    receivedNs.Close();
                    tcpReceiver.Close();
                    ssTcpListener.Stop();
                    //image.Dispose();
                    //receivedMs.Close();
                }                    
                else
                {
                    labelText("Not Connected!!!");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "frmVoiceChat-ReceiveSS()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, I know there's a lot of commented code there but at the moment I just want to get the two to connect. I'm used to dealing with UDP which aren't required to connect as they just throw the data out there and hope it gets there but image files are too large.

Comment: you should use the `using` statement.

Comment: You have *two* calls to `AcceptTcpClient` - this code won't run until *two* clients connect. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `AcceptTcpClient()` twice. The second call will wait for a connection and block the rest of the code from executing. Please clean up your code.

Comment: It's also easy to find these kinds of problems if you step through each line in the debugger. It would have revealed that execution is stopping there.